# my UI isn't working (buttons)

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have an app and all of a sudden my user interface stopped working the share button works and also the options menu but for some odd reason my buttons stopped working they don't click or do anything  . is it due to possibly the extending of my OptionsMenu class ? I have no idea why ? Does this happen often I tries to freshly build my project but no use . I have my MainActivity Class here

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.media.*;
import javax.security.auth.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.http.util.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import java.text.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.widget.TextView.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.widget.ActionMenuView.*;
import android.view.MenuItem.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.*;
import android.*;
public class MainActivity extends OptionsMenu
{
private MusicPlayer musicPlayer;
private String pos = "";
private FileManager fm;
private BlueTheme BlueTheme;
private PinkTheme PinkTheme;
private Downloader downloader;
private EditTextCustomizable etc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    musicPlayer = new MusicPlayer(new MediaPlayer());
    fm = new FileManager(this,this);
    BlueTheme = new BlueTheme(this,this ,fm);
    PinkTheme = new PinkTheme(this,this,fm);
    etc = new EditTextCustomizable(this , BlueTheme , PinkTheme);
    etc.customize();
    Button rewind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rewind);
    rewind.setText("<");
    Button fwd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fwd);
    fwd.setText(">");
    ListView downloadsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloads);
    downloadsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3){
                ListView downloadsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloads);
                 pos = downloadsList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                musicPlayer.InitPlay(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + "/" + pos);
            }});
}
public void Play(View view){
    musicPlayer.Play();
    EditText search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
    musicPlayer.SearchResult(search.getText().toString());
}


public void Pause(View view){
    musicPlayer.Pause();
}

public void Stop(View view){
    musicPlayer.Stop();
    }
public void Rewind(View view){
    musicPlayer.Rewind();
}

public void Fwd(View view){
    musicPlayer.Fwd();
}

public void onDownloadClick(View view){
    EditText bar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
    String downloadFile = bar.getText().toString();
    downloader.DownloadURL(downloadFile);
}
}
```

And here is the OptionsMenu class where I am extending Activity note that I am not using AppCompatActivity .

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.*;
import java.io.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.*;
public class OptionsMenu extends Activity
{
private MusicPlayer musicPlayer;
private FileManager fm;
private BlueTheme blueTheme;
private PinkTheme pinkTheme;
private final int blue = Menu.FIRST;
private final int pink = blue + 1;
private int items = 0;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    fm = new FileManager(this,this);
    blueTheme = new BlueTheme(this,this,fm);
    pinkTheme = new PinkTheme(this,this,fm);
    fm.ListFiles();
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflator = getMenuInflater();
    inflator.inflate(R.menu.sidebar_menu, menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Themes");
    subMenu.add(0 , blue , 0 , "Blue");
    subMenu.add(0, pink , 1, "Pink");
    items = subMenu.getItem().getItemId();

    // tool bar menu
    ArrayList<Uri> al = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ArrayList<Uri> emailAl = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.searchable);
    MenuItem share = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
    mi.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);
    SearchView  searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchable).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    ShareActionProvider sap = (ShareActionProvider) share.getActionProvider();
    Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intentShare.setType("audio/mp3");
    intentEmail.setType("audio/mp3");
    Uri uri = null;
    Uri uriEmail = null;
    //FileInputStream in = null;
    //FileOutputStream out = null;
    //try{
    //  for(File file : downloads){
    //  uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    //      in = new FileInputStream(file);
    //      File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), file.getName()); // IMPORTANT! You need to create your file object separately, so you can then pass it to intent as well.. 
    //      out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    //  byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
    //      int len;
    //      while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
    //      out.write(buf, 0, len);
    //          } 

    //          in.close(); 
    //          out.flush();
    //          out.close();
    //          uriEmail = Uri.fromFile(outFile); // Here you passed the parent directory file.. Pass newly created file object .. 
    //          al.add(uri); 
    //          emailAl.add(uriEmail);

    //          }

    //          } catch(IOException e){
    //              e.printStackTrace();
    //          }
    //for(File file : fm.GetDownloadFiles()){
    //  uriEmail = Uri.fromFile(fm.exportFile(file));
    //}
    emailAl.add(uriEmail);
    intentShare.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,al );
    intentEmail.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,emailAl);
    intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "Subject");
    intentEmail.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);  
    sap.setShareIntent(intentShare);
    sap.setShareIntent(intentEmail);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.playlist:

            break;
        case blue:
            blueTheme.Blue();
            break;

        case pink:
            pinkTheme.Pink();
            break;
        case R.id.muteoption:
            musicPlayer.MuteVolume();
            break;
        case R.id.unmuteoption:
            musicPlayer.UnMuteVolume();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            // TODO: Implement this method
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I can post up more code if requested. And will reedit if not clear enough thank you

**EDITED**

Here is the layout XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:windowActionBar="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/downloadsTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
    android:text="@string/downloadButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="onDownloadClick"
/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:hint="Do something"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/downloadButton"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:text="@string/pause"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Pause"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:text="@string/play"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Play"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pause"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:text="@string/stop"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Stop" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/pause"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rewind"
    android:text="@string/rewind"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:onClick="Rewind"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/stop"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fwd"
    android:text="@string/fwd"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:onClick="Fwd"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/play"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/downloads"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rewind"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't see you setting the onClickListener most of your buttons. Is it set in the layout XML? If not, that's probably the problem.

Comment: Yes all the buttons are set in the XML layout using OnClick it worked before but all of a sudden it stopped .

Comment: The OnItemClickListener isn't working either and I know the code is right (not being a rude I know I'm a novice) but it worked before now nothing no clicks or anything ?????

Comment: Any idea why ? Nothing appears in the logcat either when I click buttons it has absolutely no functionality

Answer (score 0):

Paste your layout xml if possible. I guess it's caused by something (maybe some parent view) interrupted the focus, so the child view button can't get focus.

Comment: I have posted the layout XML thank you for your help BTW